# Alias path not found on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias, selinux

I installed kind from [kubeflow kind](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/installation/localcluster-deployment/) and save it under my `$HOME/kubeflow/kind`

To run `kind` from any path, I create an alias in my `~/.bashrc` as following:

```
alias kind="./$HOME/kubeflow/kind"
source ~/.bashrc
```

When running kind on the terminal, it throw this error:

**-bash: .//home/XXXX/kubeflow/kind: No such file or directory**

What is the error here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your use of `./` in your path is wrong.  That implies a relative path from the current directory you're in, and is not necessary.

`$HOME` defaults to the **fully qualified** path for your home directory (i.e. `/home/USERNAME/`) and you do NOT need the `./` in the beginning of the path in your alias.

Answer (score 0):

as answered your path is wrong, since it's starting with `./`.

still, Recommended practice is to add binary path in $PATH env. instead of creating alias

`PATH=$PATH:/$HOME/kubeflow`